# jQuery Touch on Blackberry Bold 9700

Tags: blackberry, jquery

My blackberry Bold is not rendering jQuery Mobile web site properly. When I click on the navigation, it blinks and comes back to the home page again within a fractions of a second. Does jQuery not support Blackberry Bold?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

look at your phone and type of functions jQuery is executing at http://www.quirksmode.org/m/w3c_core.html